# Pass a vector of variable names to arrange() in dplyr

Tags: r, sorting, parameter-passing, dplyr

I want to pass `arrange()` {dplyr} a vector of variable names to sort on. Usually I just type in the variables I want, but I'm trying to make a function where the sorting variables can be input as a function parameter.

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L
  ), var2 = structure(c(10L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 6L
  ), .Label = c("b", "c", "f", "h", "i", "o", "s", "t", "w", "x"
  ), class = "factor"), var3 = c(7L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 
  5L, 8L), var4 = structure(c(8L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 
  2L), .Label = c("b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h", "i", "w", "y"), 
  class = "factor")), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

# this is the normal way to arrange df with dplyr
df %>% arrange(var3, var4)

# but none of these (below) work for passing a vector of variables
vector_of_vars <- c("var3", "var4")
df %>% arrange(vector_of_vars)
df %>% arrange(get(vector_of_vars))
df %>% arrange(eval(parse(text = paste(vector_of_vars, collapse = ", "))))
```

Comment: Imo, use of %>% should be saved for chaining, as it's pretty ugly... (for single actions <- or = works just fine...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Hadley hasn't made this obvious in the help file--only in his NSE vignette.  The versions of the functions followed by underscores use standard evaluation, so you pass them vectors of strings and the like.

If I understand your problem correctly, you can just replace `arrange()` with `arrange_()` and it will work.

Specifically, pass the vector of strings as the `.dots` argument when you do it.

```
> df %>% arrange_(.dots=c("var1","var3"))
   var1 var2 var3 var4
1     1    i    5    i
2     1    x    7    w
3     1    h    8    e
4     2    b    5    f
5     2    t    5    b
6     2    w    7    h
7     3    s    6    d
8     3    f    8    e
9     4    c    5    y
10    4    o    8    c
```

========== Update March 2018 ==============

Using the standard evaluation versions in dplyr as I have shown here **is now considered deprecated**.  You can read [Hadley's programming vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for the new way.  Basically you will use `!!` to unquote one variable or `!!!` to unquote a vector of variables inside of `arrange()`.

When you pass those columns, if they are bare, quote them using `quo()` for one variable or `quos()` for a vector. Don't use quotation marks. See the answer by Akrun.

If your columns are already strings, then make them names using `rlang::sym()` for a single column or `rlang::syms()` for a vector.  See the answer by Christos.  You can also use `as.name()` for a single column.  Unfortunately as of this writing, the information on how to use `rlang::sym()` has not yet made it into the vignette I link to above (eventually it will be in the section on "variadic quasiquotation" according to his draft).

Comment: I was thinking this as well, but if you do `df %>% arrange_(vector_of_vars)`, it seems to ignore the second element and sorts only on the first element. However, if you do `df %>% arrange_(vector_of_vars[1], vector_of_vars[2])`, then it sorts on both values. I assume there's a more elegant approach than the second method, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: ```arrange_()``` does seem to ignore the second column. @eipi10 your solution would work, but the problem is that there can be arbitrary number of elements in ```vector_of_vars```.

Comment: I wasn't claiming that my second method was a good one. I was just trying to bound the problem of figuring out why the seemingly "natural" approach doesn't work and also provide a temporary, if inelegant, solution. Hopefully @Hadley will jump in and edify us.

Comment: Ah, this works: ```df %>% arrange_(.dots = vector_of_vars)```. farnsy, if you make this change I'll give you credit for the answer

Comment: @farnsy What if you want to sort it in descending order? how to pass the desc parameter? I haven't figured out!

Comment: `vector_of_vars <- c("desc(var3)", "var4");df %>% arrange_(.dots=vector_of_vars)`

Comment: @farnsy this didn't work for me, see [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052325).

Answer (score 22):

In the quosures spirit:

```
df %>% arrange(!!! rlang::syms(c("var1", "var3")))
```

For single variable, it would look like:

```
df %>% arrange(!! rlang::sym(c("var1")))
```

Answer (score 20):

In the new version (soon to be released `0.6.0` of `dplyr`) we can make use of the `quosures`

```
library(dplyr)
vector_of_vars <- quos(var1, var3)
df %>%
    arrange(!!! vector_of_vars)
#   var1 var2 var3 var4
#1     1    i    5    i
#2     1    x    7    w
#3     1    h    8    e
#4     2    b    5    f
#5     2    t    5    b
#6     2    w    7    h
#7     3    s    6    d
#8     3    f    8    e
#9     4    c    5    y
#10    4    o    8    c
```

When there are more than one variable, we use `quos` and for a single variable it is `quo`.  The `quos` will return a `list` of quoted variables and inside `arrange`, we unquote the `list` using `!!!` for evaluation

Comment: ... which is now deprecated again...  `1: Unquoting language objects with '!!!' is soft-deprecated as of rlang 0.3.0. Please use '!!' instead.`  It's mindblowing (to stay polite) how many functions are constantly being deprecated in the tidyverse...  I'll go back to Base R for my long term code I think...

Answer (score 19):

I think now you can just use `dplyr::arrange_at()`.

```r
library(dplyr)

### original
head(iris)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

### arranged
iris %>% 
  arrange_at(c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")) %>% 
  head()
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
# 2          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 5          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
# 6          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: This worked for me. Holy crap there are so many syntax changes over the years for something so fundamental.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little dense, but I think the best approach now is to use `across()` along with a tidyselect function, e.g. `all_of()`:

```
df <- structure(list(var1 = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L
  ), var2 = structure(c(10L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 2L, 6L
  ), .Label = c("b", "c", "f", "h", "i", "o", "s", "t", "w", "x"
  ), class = "factor"), var3 = c(7L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 
  5L, 8L), var4 = structure(c(8L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 
  2L), .Label = c("b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h", "i", "w", "y"), 
  class = "factor")), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

vector_of_vars <- c("var3", "var4")

df %>% arrange(across(all_of(vector_of_vars)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df %>% do(do.call(arrange_, . %>% list(.dots = vector_of_vars)))
```

and actually this can be written more simply as:

```
df %>% arrange_(.dots = vector_of_vars)
```

although at this point I think its the same as farnsy's implied solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me, see [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052325).

Comment: arrange_ is deprecated, quosures way seems to be the way to go