# arrange_() multiple columns with descending order

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use `arrange_()` with string input and in one of the columns in descending order.

```
library(dplyr) # R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03) , dplyr_0.4.3 
# data
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(grp = factor(c(1,2,1,2,1)),
                  x = round(runif(5,1,10), 2))

#   grp    x
# 1   1 3.39
# 2   2 4.35
# 3   1 6.16
# 4   2 9.17
# 5   1 2.82
```

Below is what I need to achieve:

```
df1 %>% arrange(grp, -x)
df1 %>% arrange(grp, desc(x))
#   grp    x
# 1   1 6.16
# 2   1 3.39
# 3   1 2.82
# 4   2 9.17
# 5   2 4.35
```

In my case second column is a string:

```
#dynamic string
myCol <- "x"

#failed attempts
df1 %>% arrange_("grp", desc(myCol))
```

> Error: incorrect size (1), expecting : 5

```
df1 %>% arrange_("grp", "desc(myCol)")
```

> Error: object 'myCol' not found

```
df1 %>% arrange_(c("grp", "desc(myCol)"))
#wrong output
#   grp    x
# 1   1 3.39
# 2   1 6.16
# 3   1 2.82
# 4   2 4.35
# 5   2 9.17
```

I found similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497751), but couldn't make it work:

```
df1 %>% arrange_(.dots = c("grp", "desc(myCol)"))
```

> Error: object 'myCol' not found

Feels like I am missing something very obvious, ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can `paste` 'desc' as a string to evaluate it.

```
myCol1 <- paste0("desc(", "x)")
df1 %>% 
     arrange_(.dots = c("grp", myCol1))
#  grp    x
#1   1 6.16
#2   1 3.39
#3   1 2.82
#4   2 9.17
#5   2 4.35
```

Or with 'myCol'

```
df1 %>% 
      arrange_(.dots = c("grp", paste0("desc(", myCol, ")")))
```

Or use `lazyeval`

```
library(lazyeval)
df1 %>%
     arrange_(.dots = c("grp", interp(~ desc(n1), n1 = as.name(myCol))))
#  grp    x
#1   1 6.16
#2   1 3.39
#3   1 2.82
#4   2 9.17
#5   2 4.35
```

---

By using `"desc(myCol)"`, it is a single string and the value of the 'myCol' is not evaluated.

#### Update

Or another option is `parse_expr` (from `rlang`) and evaluate with `!!`

```
df1 %>%
    arrange(grp, !! rlang::parse_expr(myCol1))
#grp    x
#1   1 6.16
#2   1 3.39
#3   1 2.82
#4   2 9.17
#5   2 4.35
```

---

Or using the original string in the OP's post.  Convert the string to symbol (`sym`), evaluate (`!!`) and arrange it in descending (`desc`) order

```
myCol <- "x"
df1 %>% 
    arrange(grp, desc(!! rlang::sym(myCol)))
# grp    x
#1   1 6.16
#2   1 3.39
#3   1 2.82
#4   2 9.17
#5   2 4.35
```

Comment: Yes, these are good alternatives, wish there was a prettier solutions avoiding paste.

Comment: @zx8754  I added an option with `interp`, but I think the one with `paste` is compact

Comment: Agreed, paste seems like a way to go, `interp` makes it look even worse (no offence).

Comment: Do you mind adding "quosures" method as well? Can't get it to work.

Comment: @zx8754  I added one option with `rlang`

Answer (score 4):

This may do the trick:
`arrange(grp, across(c(x), desc))`

`dplyr` version `1.0.5`

Comment: This is the most elegant and up to date solution.